# Hover function only applies change to hovered item

Tags: html, css, hover

I tried to create an html file which would have some names in a left-floating div, and the quotes of that person in a right-floating div. The problem would of course be that if I have 40 names and 120 quotes, it would be quite chaotic.

So I came up with the idea to have all quotes ( paragraphs ) be the same color as their background. All quotes would be loaded onto the page but none would be visible. When I'd hover over Shakespeare in the div on the left, I'd have ( p:hover { color: black; } ) so that the text of a quote would become black and thus visible. So if you'd hover over Shakespeare, his paragraph having class="shakespeare", all paragraphs/quotes with the same class would suddenly be visible.

It didn't work, if I'd hover over Shakespeare only thát paragraph, the hovered-over paragraph, would become black, but not his quotes in the div on the right, even though they had the same class and I'd have : .shakespeare p:hover { ... } . So I tried to simplify it to : p:hover { } , all quotes should have become black, but I only tried it to see if this worked. This didn't work either. Anyone have a clue? I'm not really into javascript so html/css would be best. The solution isn't really important, I just don't understand why the hover function only implements the hovered-over item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, because of the difficulties of talking between 2 divs that are not related, everything has to be in the same div. I believe this answer is what you are looking for. You should be setting the `display` property, contrary to what I said before. I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.

As far as your question goes :

> The solution isn't really important, I just don't understand why the hover function only implements the hovered-over item.

It depends on how you select it. You cannot travel up the DOM tree with hovered elements but you can travel down.

So if you have some nested elements like what I have below you can apply the style to any child or sibling element.

### HTML

```
<div id="people">
    <div class="person">Shakespear
        <ul class="quotes">
            <li>"We know what we are, but know not what we may be."</li>
            <li>"It is not in the stars to hold our destiny but in ourselves."</li>
            <li>"This life, which had been the tomb of his virtue and of his honour, is but a walking shadow; a poor player, that struts and frets his hour upon the stage, and then is heard no more: it is a tale told by an idiot, full of sound and fury, signifying nothing."</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="person">Galileo
        <ul class="quotes">
            <li>"I have never met a man so ignorant that I couldn't learn something from him."</li>
            <li>"I do not feel obliged to believe that the same God who has endowed us with sense, reason, and intellect has intended us to forgo their use."</li>
            <li>“You cannot teach a man anything, you can only help him find it within himself.”</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#people {
    position: relative;
}

.person {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
}

.quotes {
    display: none;
}

.person:hover .quotes {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adjit/DpKA9/3/)

Answer (score 2):

The `:hover` portion of a selector is a pseudo-class. It describes a "state" of that element. In order to trigger the hover state, you need to hover over that element. By hovering over your `div` on the left, you don't trigger the hover state on the `p` in the `div` on the right side.

To be more specific, the `:hover` state is triggered on that element. It's not triggered on every element with that tag, class, or however you set it up. For instance, with your `p:hover` example, hover is applied to the paragraph you hover over, not every paragraph on the page.

In order to be able to be able to use the hover state to trigger the visibility of an element, it needs to be contained within the element being hovered. For example, take the following example:

```
<div class="faq-section">
    <h1 class="faq-title">I am the best of titles</h1>
    <p class="faq-description">There are no words to describe it.</p>
</div>
```

As it stands, this would be a block with a big title and a paragraph below it. You want to add a hover effect to this so when you hover over the `h1`, the `p` becomes visible.

First, you'll need to make sure the the paragraph is hidden by default.

```
.faq-description {
    display: none;
}
```

You should use `display: none;` because it hides the content as if it was not there. From an accessibility standpoint, you should not hide content on the basis of color. Screen readers wouldn't be able to differentiate. If you want the location of the hidden paragraph to continue to take up its space, though, you can use `visibility: none;`.

Now, you want to add the hover behavior. You want to affect `.faq-description`'s `display` property when you hover over this faq.

```
.faq-section:hover > .faq-description {
      display: block;
}
```

Here is a sample: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C32xZ/)

Answer (score 0):

The hover function only affects the hovered over item because that is what you are applying the css to with the pseudo-selector `element:hover`. In other words, a `p` element will only be selected to have style applied to it if it is currently being hovered over, meaning the rest of the `p` elements on the page will not have the same style applied, because they aren't being hovered over. To have css applied to another item when an item is hovered over, you will need something in the form of

```
element:hover selector-for-element-to-change {
    color:black;
}
```

I might also suggest using `visibilty: hidden` to hide the element and `visibility: visible` to show the element.

Javascript is probably the best way to go about this problem in reality, because it will often be easier to implement a selector for the item to change (just because of the way CSS selectors work). For Javascript you would use something like

```
document.getElementById("id-of-element").onmouseover=function(){
    document.getElementById("id-of-element-to-change").style.visibility = "visible";
};
```

And to hide the element after the mouse leaves:

```
document.getElementById("id-of-element").onmouseout=function(){
    document.getElementById("id-of-element-to-change").style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```

Edit:
[Here is a jsfiddle with an example of the css method.](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdoherty/6rUPx/)

[And here is a jsfiddle showing the javascript method.](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdoherty/xdZEA/)